# iOS8 localization can't fallback to English

Tags: ios, localization, ios8, xcode6.1

My app support English and Chinese, bug when I install it on the iOS8 with system language France, the  localization can not fallback to English, it choose Chinese.

I tested on iOS7 and iOS8.1, the iOS7 is correctly fallback to English, the iOS8.1 can't do that.

Is there some setting for iOS8 to choose the fallback language?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually determined by the device. If you go into Settings:General:Language&Region, you'll se there is a preferred language order. Update that so English is the preferred language and it should work right.